# Is it possible to reboot the Nexus 4 without root?

Tags: nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean, reboot

On the Nexus 4, the power menu only allows you to shutdown the device, but not reboot the device. Of course, you could wait for the device to shutdown and then power it up again. What I'm looking for is the ability to reboot in one action.

A lot of apps provide this ability, but it seems that they all requires root.

Is it possible to reboot the Nexus 4 without root?

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution: `adb reboot`

This requires connecting the device to a computer, so it's not perfect, but it works pretty well if I just want to reboot it when I go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 4 but I have an original 7. You can get a reboot on the 7 by pushing and holding the power button until it reboots. So try that. Sometimes you can go to the shut down menu and long press where it says shut down, but that may just be mods. But if it were me I'd try those, just to try it. :-)